# Application error message when trying to open heroku app website

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

When i try to open heroku app i get error message:

Application Error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.
If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.

- I ran "bundle install"

Maybe someone can help me to solve it?

```
2016-09-29T00:17:54.350531+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
2016-09-29T00:17:54.350530+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in `start'
2016-09-29T00:17:54.350531+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
2016-09-29T00:17:54.350532+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
2016-09-29T00:17:54.350533+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2016-09-29T00:17:54.350533+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:9:in `require'
2016-09-29T00:17:54.350532+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
2016-09-29T00:17:54.350534+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
2016-09-29T00:17:54.350564+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-09-29 00:17:54] INFO  going to shutdown ...
2016-09-29T00:17:54.350599+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-09-29 00:17:54] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
2016-09-29T00:17:54.377765+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2016-09-29T00:17:54.377769+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.2.6 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:48399
2016-09-29T00:17:54.377769+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2016-09-29T00:17:54.377770+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2016-09-29T00:17:54.377771+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2016-09-29T00:17:54.456019+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2016-09-30T03:46:40.166669+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
2016-09-30T03:46:40.167040+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2016-09-30T03:46:43.897264+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 14644 -e production`
2016-09-30T03:46:49.164642+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-09-30 03:46:49] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2016-09-30T03:46:49.164698+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-09-30 03:46:49] INFO  ruby 2.2.4 (2015-12-16) [x86_64-linux]
2016-09-30T03:46:49.165011+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-09-30 03:46:49] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=3 port=14644
2016-09-30T03:46:49.846719+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2016-09-30T03:46:50.402177+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=peaceful-harbor-94373.herokuapp.com request_id=f226ba60-2f3c-4da0-94a3-bcdfdac32582 fwd="80.5.78.145" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=191ms status=200 bytes=2241
2016-09-30T03:46:50.648396+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-32aca96fccef5b517f233b349393ff0335e17dd66d613cfc701f61bf0d230635.js" host=peaceful-harbor-94373.herokuapp.com request_id=37d611b5-e855-4d27-b919-01b23d6c1493 fwd="80.5.78.145" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=304 bytes=133
2016-09-30T03:46:50.771366+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-48d9e380c235a637aef423e4beef48e3de0b4e035088abb950df962b638d8778.css" host=peaceful-harbor-94373.herokuapp.com request_id=5ba6ef41-bcc9-4b36-9348-a7312c922d7b fwd="80.5.78.145" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=8ms status=304 bytes=133
2016-09-30T03:46:51.024021+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/hd-95f799e2cb057b779ee6928636294c756a4ee491bb0961f138de390e63d1b928.jpg" host=peaceful-harbor-94373.herokuapp.com request_id=00c74a83-cedb-45dc-8b6d-939a043e3ec0 fwd="80.5.78.145" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=8ms status=304 bytes=133
2016-09-30T03:46:51.601433+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=peaceful-harbor-94373.herokuapp.com request_id=2aa73ec3-3b95-4516-ba5f-d2a5ac1b793d fwd="80.5.78.145" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=6ms status=304 bytes=133
2016-09-30T03:50:40.613151+00:00 heroku[api]: Set maintenance mode off by teniauskas.kristis@gmail.com
2016-09-30T03:53:51.173465+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=choppers.herokuapp.com request_id=5b126745-84fe-43d1-b1e5-7617bc290157 fwd="80.5.78.145" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=11ms status=200 bytes=2241
2016-09-30T03:53:51.315922+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-48d9e380c235a637aef423e4beef48e3de0b4e035088abb950df962b638d8778.css" host=choppers.herokuapp.com request_id=a831c6b7-67fb-4b14-a0a6-379827d3f1b7 fwd="80.5.78.145" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=6ms status=200 bytes=470
2016-09-30T03:53:51.335531+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-32aca96fccef5b517f233b349393ff0335e17dd66d613cfc701f61bf0d230635.js" host=choppers.herokuapp.com request_id=4a09210d-b8e2-4199-80c0-29a3d1ff7221 fwd="80.5.78.145" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=9ms status=200 bytes=43915
2016-09-30T03:53:51.443069+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/hd-95f799e2cb057b779ee6928636294c756a4ee491bb0961f138de390e63d1b928.jpg" host=choppers.herokuapp.com request_id=254caa96-e3a4-4bf7-8e33-6755b7592c5d fwd="80.5.78.145" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=7ms status=200 bytes=126418
2016-09-30T03:53:52.261394+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=choppers.herokuapp.com request_id=07956f2c-629f-4044-97e0-0b6b6dabda7a fwd="80.5.78.145" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=11ms status=200 bytes=228
2016-09-30T04:04:19.284092+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=choppers.herokuapp.com request_id=34daecb7-3da9-4d77-bbaa-3cc7a55beade fwd="80.5.78.145" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=7ms status=200 bytes=2241
2016-09-30T04:04:19.487365+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-48d9e380c235a637aef423e4beef48e3de0b4e035088abb950df962b638d8778.css" host=choppers.herokuapp.com request_id=11bdafe1-d31c-4166-a999-01c23e801c89 fwd="80.5.78.145" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=200 bytes=470
2016-09-30T04:04:19.621163+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-32aca96fccef5b517f233b349393ff0335e17dd66d613cfc701f61bf0d230635.js" host=choppers.herokuapp.com request_id=bc1b73db-993d-476f-9c8f-e0af7a763b2d fwd="80.5.78.145" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=4ms status=200 bytes=43915
2016-09-30T04:04:19.651764+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/hd-95f799e2cb057b779ee6928636294c756a4ee491bb0961f138de390e63d1b928.jpg" host=choppers.herokuapp.com request_id=74c5975a-ff2e-4f79-942a-59a0e4259674 fwd="80.5.78.145" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=7ms status=200 bytes=126418
2016-09-30T04:06:24.267755+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 9cecb7a by teniauskas.kristis@gmail.com
2016-09-30T04:06:24.267755+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v6 created by teniauskas.kristis@gmail.com
2016-09-30T04:06:24.497083+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2016-09-30T04:06:24.497092+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2016-09-30T04:06:25.302316+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Restarting
2016-09-30T04:06:25.302855+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to starting
2016-09-30T04:06:28.035488+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb`
2016-09-30T04:06:28.998306+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2016-09-30T04:06:30.224705+00:00 app[web.1]: Warning: the running version of Bundler is older than the version that created the lockfile. We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
2016-09-30T04:06:30.231081+00:00 app[web.1]: Install missing gem executables with `bundle install`
2016-09-30T04:06:30.231051+00:00 app[web.1]: bundler: command not found: puma
2016-09-30T04:06:30.137938+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-09-30 04:06:30] FATAL SignalException: SIGTERM
2016-09-30T04:06:30.137950+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:174:in `select'
2016-09-30T04:06:30.137952+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:174:in `block in start'
2016-09-30T04:06:30.137953+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:32:in `start'
2016-09-30T04:06:30.137954+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-2.2.4/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:162:in `start'
2016-09-30T04:06:30.137955+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:34:in `run'
2016-09-30T04:06:30.137955+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:286:in `start'
2016-09-30T04:06:30.137956+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:80:in `start'
2016-09-30T04:06:30.137958+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
2016-09-30T04:06:30.137958+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
2016-09-30T04:06:30.137959+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
2016-09-30T04:06:30.137960+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
2016-09-30T04:06:30.137960+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
2016-09-30T04:06:30.137962+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:9:in `require'
2016-09-30T04:06:30.137963+00:00 app[web.1]:    bin/rails:9:in `<main>'
2016-09-30T04:06:30.138044+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-09-30 04:06:30] INFO  going to shutdown ...
2016-09-30T04:06:30.138099+00:00 app[web.1]: [2016-09-30 04:06:30] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
2016-09-30T04:06:30.245271+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2016-09-30T04:06:30.245275+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.2.6 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:14644
2016-09-30T04:06:30.245277+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2016-09-30T04:06:30.245277+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2016-09-30T04:06:30.245281+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2016-09-30T04:06:30.302465+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-09-30T04:06:30.303639+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2016-09-30T04:06:30.287667+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2016-09-30T04:06:30.403946+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 143
2016-09-30T04:06:33.104488+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb`
2016-09-30T04:06:34.997379+00:00 app[web.1]: Warning: the running version of Bundler is older than the version that created the lockfile. We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
2016-09-30T04:06:35.003401+00:00 app[web.1]: bundler: command not found: puma
2016-09-30T04:06:35.003405+00:00 app[web.1]: Install missing gem executables with `bundle install`
2016-09-30T04:06:35.094109+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2016-09-30T04:06:35.075761+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 127
2016-09-30T04:06:36.299893+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=choppers.herokuapp.com request_id=111c6f87-2cce-4291-8e00-0ee5306eb71f fwd="80.5.78.145" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-09-30T04:06:37.140401+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=choppers.herokuapp.com request_id=71025bd5-4624-4363-8a83-1dbe75dcd64b fwd="80.5.78.145" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-09-30T04:06:44.663469+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=choppers.herokuapp.com request_id=72a1fc04-4b16-4d02-ad77-28f601b173e6 fwd="80.5.78.145" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-09-30T04:06:45.075420+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=choppers.herokuapp.com request_id=694df0e1-0a25-46f7-ad28-429e3744dc1f fwd="80.5.78.145" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-09-30T04:07:03.581306+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=choppers.herokuapp.com request_id=222c3df4-24ec-4cd2-9c60-4ec33008e8de fwd="80.5.78.145" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-09-30T04:07:03.833973+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=choppers.herokuapp.com request_id=79d44c0c-22cb-4da0-b5cc-4b7df570e500 fwd="80.5.78.145" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-09-30T04:08:29.415909+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=choppers.herokuapp.com request_id=a853590a-c6ec-403b-b78d-7491f5ce5b0c fwd="80.5.78.145" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-09-30T04:08:29.708599+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=choppers.herokuapp.com request_id=4676efb9-6d13-438d-91f1-d35f13c86409 fwd="80.5.78.145" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-09-30T04:10:24.010270+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=choppers.herokuapp.com request_id=14c38882-a79f-455b-bbf4-6783bac0a87e fwd="80.5.78.145" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-09-30T04:10:23.640366+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=choppers.herokuapp.com request_id=9759a41c-d050-4400-8ffa-6bb775a2f856 fwd="80.5.78.145" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-09-30T04:12:26.678541+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=choppers.herokuapp.com request_id=620795ce-3bd6-4a01-adb9-7756722c9241 fwd="80.5.78.145" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-09-30T04:12:27.177195+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=choppers.herokuapp.com request_id=590f65ce-3834-4e22-a457-73d8609b5d94 fwd="80.5.78.145" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-09-30T04:12:30.558758+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=choppers.herokuapp.com request_id=75ec156a-263e-42bf-8bd7-abc3b653a297 fwd="80.5.78.145" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-09-30T04:12:30.942937+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=choppers.herokuapp.com request_id=12843449-837b-4233-90a1-4d7e12d4dc13 fwd="80.5.78.145" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-09-30T04:35:32.352931+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2016-09-30T04:37:28.849754+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2016-09-30T04:37:53.283056+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2016-09-30T04:38:11.090490+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=choppers.herokuapp.com request_id=172cdad6-5161-4edf-8bb6-b6703fa734f9 fwd="80.5.78.145" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-09-30T04:38:11.467715+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=choppers.herokuapp.com request_id=cc1310cc-b003-421e-a152-9d98eafacb9a fwd="80.5.78.145" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2016-09-30T04:39:39.466994+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
```

Logs from heroku website

```
-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.2.4
-----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.11.2
       Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
       Warning: the running version of Bundler is older than the version that created the lockfile. We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
       You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing
       your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the
       updated Gemfile.lock to version control.
       You have added to the Gemfile:
       * puma (~> 3.0)
       Bundler Output: Warning: the running version of Bundler is older than the version that created the lockfile. We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.
       You are trying to install in deployment mode after changing
       your Gemfile. Run `bundle install` elsewhere and add the
       updated Gemfile.lock to version control.

       You have added to the Gemfile:
       * puma (~> 3.0)
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
 !     Push failed
```

EDIT

ok i installed 1.11.2 bundle version, but still rejecting, when i push Gemfile.

```
Counting objects: 19, done.
Compressing objects: 100% (18/18), done.
Writing objects: 100% (19/19), 2.23 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 19 (delta 11), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.2.4
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.11.2
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
remote:        Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
remote:        Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
remote:        Using rake 11.2.2
remote:        Using i18n 0.7.0
remote:        Using json 1.8.3
remote:        Using minitest 5.9.0
remote:        Using thread_safe 0.3.5
remote:        Using builder 3.2.2
remote:        Using erubis 2.7.0
remote:        Using mini_portile2 2.1.0
remote:        Using pkg-config 1.1.7
remote:        Using rack 1.6.4
remote:        Using mime-types-data 3.2016.0521
remote:        Using arel 6.0.3
remote:        Using coffee-script-source 1.10.0
remote:        Using execjs 2.7.0
remote:        Using thor 0.19.1
remote:        Using concurrent-ruby 1.0.2
remote:        Using multi_json 1.12.1
remote:        Using pg 0.19.0
remote:        Using bundler 1.11.2
remote:        Using sass 3.4.22
remote:        Using tilt 2.0.5
remote:        Using turbolinks-source 5.0.0
remote:        Using rdoc 4.2.2
remote:        Using tzinfo 1.2.2
remote:        Using nokogiri 1.6.8
remote:        Using mime-types 3.1
remote:        Using rack-test 0.6.3
remote:        Using coffee-script 2.4.1
remote:        Using uglifier 3.0.2
remote:        Using sprockets 3.7.0
remote:        Using turbolinks 5.0.1
remote:        Using activesupport 4.2.6
remote:        Using sdoc 0.4.1
remote:        Using mail 2.6.4
remote:        Using loofah 2.0.3
remote:        Using rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3
remote:        Using globalid 0.3.7
remote:        Using activemodel 4.2.6
remote:        Using jbuilder 2.6.0
remote:        Using rails-html-sanitizer 1.0.3
remote:        Using rails-dom-testing 1.0.7
remote:        Using activerecord 4.2.6
remote:        Using activejob 4.2.6
remote:        Using actionview 4.2.6
remote:        Using actionpack 4.2.6
remote:        Using actionmailer 4.2.6
remote:        Using railties 4.2.6
remote:        Using sprockets-rails 3.1.1
remote:        Using coffee-rails 4.1.1
remote:        Using jquery-rails 4.2.1
remote:        Using rails 4.2.6
remote:        Using sass-rails 5.0.6
remote:        Installing puma 3.6.0 with native extensions
remote:        Bundle complete! 14 Gemfile dependencies, 53 gems now installed.
remote:        Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
remote:        Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.
remote:        Bundle completed (5.63s)
remote:        Cleaning up the bundler cache.
remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        SyntaxError: /tmp/build_fa26cd38a82ac06672bf2f99e38da7bf/config/environments/production.rb:86: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end
remote:        /tmp/build_fa26cd38a82ac06672bf2f99e38da7bf/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_fa26cd38a82ac06672bf2f99e38da7bf/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
remote:        /tmp/build_fa26cd38a82ac06672bf2f99e38da7bf/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
remote:        /tmp/build_fa26cd38a82ac06672bf2f99e38da7bf/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_fa26cd38a82ac06672bf2f99e38da7bf/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:598:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
remote:        /tmp/build_fa26cd38a82ac06672bf2f99e38da7bf/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:597:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_fa26cd38a82ac06672bf2f99e38da7bf/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/engine.rb:597:in `block in <class:Engine>'
remote:        /tmp/build_fa26cd38a82ac06672bf2f99e38da7bf/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
remote:        /tmp/build_fa26cd38a82ac06672bf2f99e38da7bf/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
remote:        /tmp/build_fa26cd38a82ac06672bf2f99e38da7bf/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
remote:        /tmp/build_fa26cd38a82ac06672bf2f99e38da7bf/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_fa26cd38a82ac06672bf2f99e38da7bf/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:44:in `tsort_each_child'
remote:        /tmp/build_fa26cd38a82ac06672bf2f99e38da7bf/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
remote:        /tmp/build_fa26cd38a82ac06672bf2f99e38da7bf/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
remote:        /tmp/build_fa26cd38a82ac06672bf2f99e38da7bf/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        /tmp/build_fa26cd38a82ac06672bf2f99e38da7bf/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require'
remote:        /tmp/build_fa26cd38a82ac06672bf2f99e38da7bf/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:328:in `require_environment!'
remote:        /tmp/build_fa26cd38a82ac06672bf2f99e38da7bf/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.6/lib/rails/application.rb:457:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
remote:        /tmp/build_fa26cd38a82ac06672bf2f99e38da7bf/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.1.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:62:in `block (2 levels) in define'
remote:        /tmp/build_fa26cd38a82ac06672bf2f99e38da7bf/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.2.0/gems/rake-11.2.2/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
remote:        Tasks: TOP => environment
remote:        (See full trace by running task with --trace)
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to choppers.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/choppers.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/choppers.git'
```

I solve it, something was wrong with production.rb file

Comment: Have you pushed gemfile.lock to your git repository after you changed gemfile?

Comment: No, but now i can't to push it.


Warning: the running version of Bundler is older than the version that created the lockfile. We suggest you upgrade to the latest version of Bundler by running `gem install bundler`.

[remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to

Comment: try "gem install bundler", and check  if it allows you to push gemfile.lock to git branch.

Comment: Don't allow to push, i get the same

Comment: Now you can see gem related issue is resolved, 'puma' is installed and bundler has completed. This issue is with the next command 'rake assets:precompile',  which is because of syntax error at /config/environments/production.rb:86, please check for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it's complaining that the version of bundler installed on heroku is older than the version you used to create your Gemfile.lock on your dev machine.

Looking at log heroku is using bundler 1.11.2, check which bundler version you are using. If its different then try following on your dev machine:

```
gem uninstall bundler
gem install bundler -v 1.11.2
```

Then you need to do either of following:

1) Regenerate your Gemfile.lock such that it says it was bundled with 1.11.2.(recommended but it may be painful)

OR

2) Go and edit bundler version in the Gemfile.lock by hand.

Once done, now push your updated gemfile.lock file to git branch.

Comment: @Kristis......If this answer helped you to get rid of bundler and gemfile.lock related issue, please accept it.

Answer (score 0):

According to your logs your bundle is completed. Scroll down and you'll notice it is complaining about a Syntax error

`SyntaxError: /tmp/build_fa26cd38a82ac06672bf2f99e38da7bf/config/environments/production.rb:86: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end`

Check the file and line number

Comment: 85  config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
  86  end

Comment: I cannot tell form this line what the problem is. It shows an `end` keyword but not it's associated `do` and I can't make any assumption. You need to check the file for syntax errors. Check for any syntax error, code blocks that are not properly closed, or extra block statements. Some good ol' debugging will do the trick :) 
Alternatively you could show the code if debugging is becoming a pain

Comment: If you use Atom text editor you can download rubocop [here] (https://atom.io/packages/linter-rubocop) to check your code for syntax errors. Alternatively you can also run this command `ruby -c filename.rb` from command line to check for syntax errors in the file